# Combinar resultados inner en una columna

Tags: postgresql

Buenas gente tengo esta duda si tengo esta consulta

```
TA
| id | Nombre |Ganancia |
| 1  | Luis   | 20      |
| 2  | Pedro  | 30      |
| 3  | Miguel | 50      |

TB
| Nombre   | Perdidas|
| Luis     | -10     |
| Pedro    | -5      |
 
select A.id,B.nombre,A.ganancias,B.perdidas
from tablaA A
inner join tablaB B
on A.id=B.id;
```

Como puedo combinar el resultado de A.gastos y B.perdidas para que quede en una sola columna

Es decir quiero que me quede de esta manera

```
TResul
TA
| id | Nombre |GananciaPerdida |
| 1  | Luis   | 20             |
| 1  | Luis   | -10            |
| 2  | Pedro  | 30             |
| 2  | Pedro  | -5             |
```

Trate de hacerlo con UNION en vez de INNER pero me trae los resultados que no coinciden en ambas tablas es decir

```
TResul
TA
| id | Nombre |GananciaPerdida |
| 1  | Luis   | 20             |
| 1  | Luis   | -10            |
| 2  | Pedro  | 30             |
| 2  | Pedro  | -5             |
| 3  | NULL   | 30             |
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes unir las dos consultas, la de ganancias y la de pérdidas de forma independiente mediante un `UNION ALL` y usar esta como sub consulta:

```
SELECT T.id,
       T.nombre,
       T.GanciaPerdida
       FROM (
              SELECT id, 
                     nombre,
                     ganancias AS 'GananciaPerdida',
                     FROM TablaA

              UNION ALL

              SELECT id, 
                     nombre,
                     perdidas AS 'GananciaPerdida',
                     FROM TablaB
       ) T
       ORDER BY T.id,
                T.nombre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero me sigue trayendo el resultado de null

Comment: No Luis de esta forma es imposible que te traiga un Nombre como null, a menos que el Nombre sea Null

Answer (score -1):

```
Select a. id, a. nombre, ( a. ganancia + b. perdida)
From TA a
Join TB b ON a.nombre = b.nombre
```

Comment: Estaria genial que dieras una explicación de lo que hace tu código. Le vendria bien tanto a OP como a aquellos que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.